IEEEtran not found even though its installed
tlmgr shows that ieeetran is installed
➜  ~ tlmgr info ieeetran                      
package:     ieeetran
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Document class for IEEE Transactions journals and conferences
longdesc:    The class and its BibTeX style enable authors to produce officially-correct output for the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE) transactions, journals and conferences.
installed:   Yes
revision:    59672
sizes:       doc: 993k, run: 821k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.8b
cat-license: lppl1.3
cat-topics:  journalpub class
cat-contact-home: http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
collection:  collection-publishers

However I try to compile with pdflatex and I get the following error
➜  pdflatex main
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>

! LaTeX Error: File `IEEEtran.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 

Am I doing something wrong?
MWE:
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{color} % Required for color
\usepackage{import}


\title{drra2 oscar workshop}
\author{Jordi Altayó}
\date{April 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}


What is the name of the cls file on your disk? maybe a question of upper / lowercase?

I tried both ieeetran and IEEEtran, neither worked

If you are using MikTeX I would suggest you refresh your filename database (console tasks).

I am using texlive, the cls are here: is that correct?
➜  texlive find . -iname "ieeetran.cls"
./2023/texmf-dist/doc/latex/xtuthesis/reference/IEEEtran.cls
./2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ieeetran/IEEEtran.cls
